# How to get the Namespace of a JAXB object

Tags: java, namespaces, jaxb

Currently I am marshalling a JAXB object to an output stream with the following code

```
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, Boolean.TRUE);
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
marshaller.marshal(new JAXBElement(new QName("hard_coded_namespace", clazz.getSimpleName()), clazz, obj), out);
```

I would like to replace "hard_coded_namespace" with the namespace contained within the JAXB "obj" (or one of its attributes, they currently should share the same NS).

Any ideas how to get at the NS information BEFORE marshaling? In the output stream, the Namespaces appear. So they are somewhere in the "obj".

[UPDATE] As pointed out in the answers below, I don't need to set the the JAXB_FRAGMENT property. I changed it to:

```
    JAXB.marshal(new JAXBElement<T>(new QName("hard_coded_namespace", rootName), clazz, jaxbObject), out);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For now, this is the solution I found:

```
    String nsURI = "";
    for(Annotation annotation: jaxbObject.getClass().getPackage().getAnnotations()){
        if(annotation.annotationType() == XmlSchema.class){
            nsURI = ((XmlSchema)annotation).namespace();
            break;
        }
    }
```

More elegant solutions are welcome :-)

Comment: the namespace info was in `package-info.java`

Comment: depending on how general-purpose you want your solution to be, there is no guarantee that package-info.class will be generated by xjc (see the -npa option).

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to use that marshal API? There is a simpler overloading. As long as obj's runtime class has the annotation @XmlRootElement, you should be able to simply call

```
marshaller.marshal(obj, out);
```

Comment: In this case I don't have the XmlRootElement attribute set in the object's class. The Marshaller API is necessary so that I can indicate that this is a JAXB_FRAGMENT, i.e. an element without a XmlRootElement. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Actually I am doing exactly what you recommend. It's just hard to read because of the new JAXBElement() in the middle... :-).

Answer (score 1):

The use of the `Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT` property doesn't really have anything to do with processing non-root elements. It acts as a flag to determine if certain marshaling events should be throttled. For example, if the property is set, then start and end document events will not be generated.

I haven't tested the following, but here's a basic idea of how I'd create some utility code to find the `QName` of a given JAXB object:

- If `JAXBIntrospector.isElement` returns true, then just use
  `JAXBIntrospector.getElementName`.
- Use reflection to find a method on the `ObjectFactory` class in the
  same package as the JAXB object that returns `JAXBElement` and takes
  a single argument that is an instance of the same class as the JAXB
  object. Invoke that method and then use `JAXBElement.getName`.

Comment: thanks for your answer! isElement() returns false on the objects I am dealing with.

Answer (score 0):

```
JAXBContext jaxbCtx = JAXBContext.newInstance(Instance.class);
QName qname = jaxbCtx.createJAXBIntrospector().getElementName(instance);
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is no **@XmlRootElement** on the class to serialize, no other way to look for package declaration itself (JAXBIntrospector will not work):

```
private <T> QName getQName(final Class<T> clazz) {
    // No other way since it is not @RootXmlElement
    final String xmlns;
    final Package aPackage = clazz.getPackage();
    if (aPackage.isAnnotationPresent(XmlSchema.class)) {
        xmlns = aPackage.getDeclaredAnnotation(XmlSchema.class).namespace();
    } else {
        xmlns = ""; // May throw illegal
    }
    return new QName(xmlns, clazz.getSimpleName());
}
```